# Docker restore deleted images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, restore, docker-container, docker-image

Created an ubuntu docker image. (no commits, no backups) Decided to practice and delete.

But only now I realized that I can't restore the rest :) Can restore as GIT, past images by name,ID ?

- docker run -it ubuntu ps -A
- docker ps -a
- docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
- docker images
- docker rmi ubuntu:laters
- docker rmi $(docker images -q)  #overdid it
- docker images
- docker ps -a

p.s. - also read that there are saves in folders /var/lib/docker/volumes/

Comment: Just rebuild from the Dockerfile. That's the way it's supposed to work, at least.

Comment: to be able to restore images, do I need to commit and create backups? or is there a simple restore command?

Comment: Check your Dockerfile in to source control, and then you can rebuild it as @SiHa suggests.  Never run `docker commit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a version of Docker images, you can store your image in `Amazon ECR`. If the source code is not changed, then you can rebuild the image from the `Dockerfile` and it will be the same.

If there is change in the source code, and you are using `version control` for your code, then you can checkout to that commit and build the Docker image again.